# Removing Special Characters in Word VBA

Tags: vba, special-characters, ms-word

I'm trying to make a macro to delete all special characters in a Word document, My basic reference to all special characters I need to delete for work are:

SPECIAL CHARACTERS

• Time to produce

(8 CCR §9792.24. 3),

µ  (the ‘u’ is not a letter, it is actually a symbol ‘µ’) If it documented as “µgm” in the file, and the reviewer is dictating it as “units per gram, ” then put units per gram (note in file states µgm [microgram/mcg]).

Kienböck’s

· Pain interferes…

®

©

™

· Pain interferes…

*Postsurgical physical

antagonists, α-adrenergic, cholinergic receptor agonists, γ agonists, Voltaren® Gel

•Genotype 1

treatment-naïve

≥ (add to autocorrect = greater than or equal to)

Any special characters found in above text are what I need removed from my Word document at any given time and or replaced with their respective meaning & = and, µ = micro and etc. I've tried researching to see if there are any out there but I can't seem to find any. I don't really have a set code as I'm a true novice. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. This would be in Word 2013 or 2007, as I would send this macro for my coworkers as well.

Comment: If you truly are a true novice, I suggest you simply start recording a macro. Do a search & replace (or several of them). You might then already have a macro that does exactly what you need. If not, chances are that you can extend it later by inspecting the generated VBA code. Take the generated code for one search & replace as a template, then copy&paste and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I know it's long but it seems too get the job done for me as far as what you're asking for

```
Sub SpecChar()
'
' SpecChar Macro

Dim oPara As Paragraph
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs()
        Set r = oPara.Range
        If r.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet Then
            r.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
            End If

        Set r = Nothing
Next

   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
   Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "§"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "&"
      .Replacement.Text = "and"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "µ"
      .Replacement.Text = "micro"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "°"
      .Replacement.Text = " degrees"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "±"
      .Replacement.Text = "plus/minus "
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "®"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "©"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "™"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
      .Text = ChrW(945)
      .Replacement.Text = "alpha"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = ChrW(947)
      .Replacement.Text = "y"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = ChrW(8804)
      .Replacement.Text = "less than or equal to "
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = ChrW(8805)
      .Replacement.Text = "greater than or equal to "
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
     .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "*"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "ö"
      .Replacement.Text = "o"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "æ"
      .Replacement.Text = "ae"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "ä"
      .Replacement.Text = "a"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "ï"
      .Replacement.Text = "i"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
   Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

   With Selection.Find
      .Text = "[®§™©·†o·]"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
   End With




End Sub
```